# finding a matrix $A_2$ such that $A_2(\mbox{vect}(e_2,e_3)) \subseteq \mbox{vect}(e_2,e_3)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functional-analysis

Let us consider
$$A_1 = \left[\begin{array}{ccc} 2&-1&0 \\  0&1&0\\  0&0&0\end{array}\right].$$

> I want to find a matrix $A_2$ such that $A_1A_2=A_2A_1$ and $A_2F\subseteq F$ with $F=\mbox{vect}(e_2,e_3)$

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take $A_2$ to be Identity matrix.